# Cascading GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have 3 tables: Orders, OrderItems and OrderSubItems. A table of orders that contains order items that contains itself order sub items.

So

```
Orders:
Id       | Other columns
O-123456 |
O-789123 |
O-456789 |

OrderItems:
Id        | OrderId  | Other columns
OI-123456 | O-123456 |
OI-123457 | O-123456 |
OI-123458 | O-123456 |
OI-123459 | O-456789 |
OI-123460 | O-456789 |
OI-123461 | O-456789 |

OrderSubItems:
Id         | OrderItemId  | Other columns
OSI-123456 | OI-123456    |
OSI-123457 | OI-123456    |
OSI-123458 | OI-123457    |
OSI-123459 | OI-123457    |
OSI-123460 | OI-123458    |
OSI-123461 | OI-123458    |
```

So order O-123456 has 3 order item OI-123456, OI-123457 and OI-123458. Each of these order item have 2 order sub items.

I use entity framework database first and no contraints, link are created between these 3 table. So I need to create links manually.

I already did this:

```
    Orders.GroupJoin(OrderItems, order => order.Id, orderItem => orderItem.OrderId, (order, orderItem) => new { order, orderItem })
      .GroupJoin(OrderSubItems, x => x.orderItem.Id, y => y.OrderItemId, (x, orderSubItem) => new
      {
          x.orderItem.ItemId,
          ... ???
      })
      .Dump();
```

The second GroupJoin is not compiling. My goal is to create the original structure of data. I use LinqPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `GroupJoin` is not compiling because you are calling it on the first `GroupJoin` result and not on the collection within the anonymous item being created in the first.

Formatting the query would help avoid confusion when defining the desired object type

```
var result = Orders.GroupJoin(OrderItems,
    order => order.Id,
    orderItem => orderItem.OrderId,
    (order, orderItems) => new {
        OrderId = order.Id,
        //...other properties
        OrderItems = orderItems.GroupJoin(OrderSubItems,
            orderItem => orderItem.Id,
            subItem => subItem.OrderItemId,
            (item, subItems) => new {
                ItemId = item.Id,
                //...other properties
                SubItems = subItems
            })
    });
```